# QGIS 3.4 Modeler: Select a band of a raster layer for processing

Tags: layers, qgis-modeler, band

As model input data I select a raster stack with three bands. The first processing tool just needs specific bands of this stack which I like to select in the input dialog.

I create a 'Raster Layer' input that lets me select the layer. Then, I also create a 'Raster Band' input that has the 'Raster Layer' input as parent. In the GUI that is displayed as a drop-down menu and I can choose between the bands.

However, the model always takes the first band of the raster layer, no matter which band I select. The processes following the layer/band selection are connected to the selection of the layer, because there is no possibility of selecting the bands (see screenshot):

[image]

How can I make the processing tools to use a specific band of a layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. It seems, that not all tools can work with a band selection as input. The used GDAL "Clip raster by extent" tool was not able to deal with that.
I then inserted the GDAL "Rearrange bands" tool before the clipping tool. That tool is able to choose a specific band based on the input selection and to forward it to the next tool.